# Hough Transform with Matlab

Tags: matlab, hough-transform

I'm doing some shape detecting coding with Matlab. I just want to understand the code segment

```
[H,theta,rho] = hough(BW)
```

I understand the conversion of the `x,y` coordinates to the `theta,rho` coordinate system. What I can't understood is the format of the output of `hough(BW)` function. Simply the Question is what is the `[H,theta,rho]`here. It's better I can get a clear idea about the `Hough Transformation Matrix (H)` with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the documentation of the [`hough`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/hough.html) function carefully.
Here is a clear explanation what is `H`, `theta` and `rho`:

> The function returns `H`, the Hough transform matrix.
>   `theta` (in degrees) and `rho` are the arrays of `rho` and `theta` values over which hough generates the Hough transform matrix.

Answer (score 1):

#### The H, theta, and rho

The output is a bit confusing if you're not familiar with Matlab-isms and how the Hough transform works.

H is a table of the accumulated results of the Hough transform with the dimensions rho-theta. So for each pixel in the thresholded image you calculate the rho (distance) and thetas (angles) and increment the corresponding cells by 1.

The rho and theta matrices returned are essentially the row and column headers of the H matrix.

#### A naive Hough implementation

It may help you to look at my [Naive Hough implementation for Matlab](https://gist.github.com/palmerc/a124548f985df5d3cfdc)